# Compare directory content to a text file

Tags: python

I am trying to compare the contents of a directory to a text file.I have certain files in the directory and I also want to compare the files to this text file.  How do I achieve this?

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: I  stored the contents of directory in a variable. Then I read contents of file and tried to compare the variable and file contents.but its not working

Answer (score 1):

To get the directory's content (list of filenames):

```
import os
dir_content = os.listdir(directory_path)
```

To get a text-files content (line by line in a list):

```
with open(filename) as f: 
    lines = f.readlines()
```